# Run Ruby Unit Tests(Test::Unit) inside the Code

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, command-line, tdd, bdd

Does anybody know how I do run a unit test(Test::Unit) within Ruby code itself? I couldn't find anything online to help me out. As we all know, you run unit tests from the command line by executing "ruby your_test_name.rb' I basically don't want to run from the command line but I want to run within the ruby code itself. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

How can u imagine it?

If you wanna start your code (tests) automatically after changes check out **gem guard**.

1) Setup guard

Add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'guard-test'
```

than run

```
bundle install
```

or if you don't use bundle

```
gem install guard-test
```

2) Generate guardfile

```
guard init test
```

3) Run it

```
guard
```

[more about guard](https://github.com/guard/guard-test)

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for this. It's quite interesting though this is not what I really want to do. I want to run test code within a Ruby class itself. Imagine I have a class A and I want to call the unit test from Class A directly.